# User agent for mobile application htaccess file

Tags: html, .htaccess, jquery-mobile

I have done a jquery mobile application. Now i want to run the url in mobile device only and desktop device are shoeing false.

After a long time i am trying the htaccess file in application folder where the index.html is there.

mY htaccess file is

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/http://originalsite.com/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /http://www.othersite.com/ [L,R=302]
```

NOW I can not get the effect in my site.

Is there something i missed here ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with those lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.othersite.com [L,R=302]
```