# Detecting User Agent to redirect on specific Jsp in struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, user-agent, mobile-website, interceptor

As title suggests I want to redirect the requests of mobile phones to specific page.

another way I expect is only a variable that contains information about UserAgent so That U can use that Variable in JSP to test and show specific data only

I am newbie for struts so just a    **  EXPECTING SIMPLE PROGRAM ...  **

Comment: Does your server support some kind of .htaccess?

Comment: Sorry.. I am on under-developent project in my company.. I dont know.. Tell me solution for both conditions

Comment: Try This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749109/user-agent-for-mobile-application-htaccess-file
and This: http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/detect-and-redirect-iphone/

Comment: I didn't understood it.... :(  I need a simple java program that contains a variable and that variable will store the information of user agent, I just want to deal with Mobile and desktop version of site...... So that variable I will push on to the value stack And will be tested in JSP to show or hide DIV's

Comment: Unfortunately, the only solution I know is Java independent. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

My index.jsp

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : Apr 17, 2013, 7:11:53 PM
    Author     : Prabhakar
--%>


<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Detect</title>
        <%
        String ua = request.getHeader( "User-Agent" );
        boolean isFirefox = ( ua != null && ua.indexOf( "Firefox/" ) != -1 );
        boolean isMSIE = ( ua != null && ua.indexOf( "MSIE" ) != -1 );
        response.setHeader( "Vary", "User-Agent" );
        %>
    </head>

        <% if( isMSIE ){ 
      response.sendRedirect("ie.action");

     } else if(isFirefox) { 
        response.sendRedirect("mozilla.action");
         }else{
        response.sendRedirect("default.action");
        } %>

    </body>
</html>
```